# How to turn a series of nested lists into Miller Columns?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking to display a series of nested lists as [Miller Columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_columns), with the functionality being that clicking on a parent displays the next list and so on.

I've seen various solutions which require the data to be parsed as json, but these aren't appropriate to my situation, and was hoping to do the same thing in plain html.

My markup is a standard nested list.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="">Column 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Column 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Column 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Column 1</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="">Column 2</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="">Column 3</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="">Column 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Column 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Column 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Column 4</a>

        </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Column 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Column 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Column 3</a>

        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Column 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Column 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Column 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: a good start: http://miller.mageekbox.net/ - it's easy to transform your markup into JSON...

Comment: Thanks. This was the one I'd found which uses json to populate the lists. Sadly I can't use this.

Comment: Here is a simple responsive implementation of mine. https://github.com/dsharew/responsive-miller-column. It is open source feel free to contribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Displaying the columns as Miller Columns

**[Fiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/zequeb4r/)**

This should get you most of the way there.  There are pretty simple CSS solves to this.  If you need the output in CSS as opposed to SASS, there are plenty of online/converters or compilers, but I'll include it in the answer as well.

```
ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block; }
ul > li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px; }
```

That's just using the column as the context position for each subsequent column, and then pushing it off to the right of its parent.

**EDIT**

Removed the white-space and text-overflow properties, as they're immaterial to solving this problem.

## Providing the interaction of Miller Columns

**EDIT: PART THE SECOND**

[Here's your updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/zequeb4r/3/)

Again, this is just using CSS to handle displaying columns in kind, with a jQuery helper to apply the appropriate classes.  I added some decorations because the plain text wasn't very helpful in illustrating the interaction.

Here's the additional CSS:

```
ul > li {
 background-color: #075883; }

ul > li a {
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none; }

ul > li.expanded > ul {
  overflow: visible;
  max-width: 500px;
  transition: 0.2s; }
```

Here's the necessary jQuery (can easily be done in native JS as well).

```
$('li a').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('expanded').siblings().removeClass('expanded'); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort Josh. I maybe should have been explicit in my question (I'll edit). It's the functionality of Miller Columns I'm looking for (click on a parent, display the child, click on a child, display the child's child etc), not simply the look and feel. Thanks though.

Comment: No problem, I'll update the fiddle and response in a second.  Don't need JSON for this at all.

Comment: Ta-da. That should handle the problem as described.

Comment: Thanks Josh. It's a neat solution. I'll maybe build on this, but have a tick from me!

Comment: Also, I managed to achieve more or less the same result with superclick.js which takes a typical suckerfish menu but instead of hover, uses click events to show / hide menus.

http://jsfiddle.net/mw17d00z/

Comment: Very nice. I hadn't heard of suckerfish before, now I'll have to check it out.